# Does google provide source codes for android functionalities? for example, fast scroll bar

Tags: android

I have been looking for fast scroll bar like basic phone app in android device.
I found a fast scroll bar which looks great here at https://github.com/reddit/IndicatorFastScroll

However, I can't find the fast scroll bar from google which looks like this.

[image]

Does anybody have any idea if google provide source code for this(or any dependency)?

Comment: What Google app is the scrollbar in the picture from? I don't recognise it!

Comment: @HenryTwist I am sorry, I had to say native(default) contact app instead of basic phone app. if you click on native phone app and click on contact app (or directly click on contact app), you can see fast scroll bar on the right side of the screen.

Comment: What device are you using?